# Is it an Alloy Evaluator bug?

Tags: alloy

Given the simple test below, in some instances the Evaluator answers negative cardinality.

```
sig A{}
pred show{}
run show

// 2nd instance
univ          {A$0}
#univ         -1

// 3rd instance
univ          {A$0, A$1}
#univ         -2

// 4th instance
univ          {A$0, A$1, A$2}
#univ         3
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be. But if you explicitly add integers into the universe, it returns the valid number. I mean something like `run show for 3 Int`

Comment: With integers added into the universe I get: univ: {-1, -2, -3, -4, 0, 1, 2, 3, A$0, A$1}, **#univ->univ: -4**

Comment: cardinality of `univ->univ` in your case (when the size of the universe is 10) is 100; 100 in binary is 1100100; in your case the bitwidth is set to 3, so only the last 3 bits of 1100100 (100) are taken and interpreted in two's complement, which yields -4.

Comment: Like the last case, there is no atom in the universe representing 4, so an overflow happens. If you want to get 4 to be in the universe, add more integers. `run for 4 Int` adds integers in [-2^4,2^4) to the universe.

Comment: no matter what the integer bitwidth is set to (i.e., how many more integers you add), `univ->univ` will always contain more elements than there are integers in your universe, so `#univ->univ` will always overflow.

Comment: Thanks indeed. Has bitwidth the same effect in expressions in predicates etc. when executing a 'run' or 'assert' command?

Comment: Yes, bitwidth is relevant for all integer expressions (integer constants, arithmetic operators, and the cardinality operator), no matter where they occur; for relational expressions, bitwidth has no effect.

Comment: I see the point that `#univ->univ` has to be more than the bit-width, but Alloy Evaluator does not count Integers for cardinality. In this example, if there are two atoms of `A` exist in the universe, evaluator returns 2 for #univ and 4 for #univ->univ if the bit-width is properly set.

Comment: I understand the integer overflow happening. Yet I don't understand that -1 when the univ contain only one element. How come -1 ? it's not part of the integer bandwith, just like 1 ... no ?